# My live-search element is not transforming into an input box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, livesearch

I'm using the [livesearch](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-livesearch) plugin for Angular-JS to try and create an AJAX dynamic search box. Following tutorials, I believe that I have everything set up as it should be, but when the page runs, it doesn't transform from a `<live-search>` element to an `<input>` element. I can't figure out why.

In my code, I have the scripts ordered like this:

```
<script src="/Scripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Custom/liveSearch.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Custom/application.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/Controllers/salesEventEdit.ctrl.js"></script>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hqj5L/1/) of the relevant code. If you need more, I can update it, but to make it completely functional would be a ton of code to copy over, thanks to angular. The code that I've included in the fiddle is a portion of the `salesEventEdit.ctrl.js` file.

From everything that I've read, the transformation from `<live-search>` to `<input>` should be taken care of via angular by itself and I shouldn't have to do anything.

To help with people in the future in case my fiddle disappears, here is the relevant HTML:

```
<span class="liveSearchWrap">
    <live-search type="text"
        class="liveSearch"
        name="entitySearch"
        live-search-callback="entityCallback"
        live-search-item-template="{{result.Name}}"
        live-search-select="Name"
        live-search-max-result-size="50"
        live-search-wait-timeout="500"
        live-search-selected-id="Id"
        user-id="entity.Id"></live-search>
    <a class="btnSearch"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
</span>
```

Comment: How did you initialize `app`?

Comment: Ugh, you figured it out Ian. I forgot to add the `'LiveSearch'` to my app declaration. Do you want to make an answer, and I'll accept it when I get home?

Comment: I had a feeling that was the problem :) Yep, I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the **LiveSearch** module **does** automatically handle `<live-search>` elements, it needs to be injected into the application. As shown in the GitHub page's README [here](https://github.com/mauriciogentile/angular-livesearch/blob/master/readme.md), inject it like so:

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["LiveSearch"]);
// -------------------------HERE --^
```

Comment: Thanks! Of course it was something stupid like that.